# Is it possible to hide data in cells based on conditions in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

There is a Google Spreadsheet document that Account A and Account B create together.

They absolutely need to be used together, but some data you don't want to show to each other.

For example, in a sheet called ‘Summary’

Suppose that a person named Foo manages the data of A2:G50, and a person named Bar manages the data of I2:O50.

If you log in with your Foo account, open the 'Summary' sheet, you should not be able to see the data for I2:O50,
If you log in with your Bar account, open the 'Summary' sheet, you should not be able to see the data for A2:G50.

The criterion for not being able to see data is not to hide cells, but to make them invisible through mosaics or other methods.

Actually, I don't think this is possible, but I'd like to ask a question anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, in a way: you can set up an `onOpen` Apps Script function that will check the user's email and hide specific rows/columns, apply different formatting, etc.

There are several limitations:

1. It will work only if the email is accessible, for example, when they belong to the same Google Workspace domain ([documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user#getemail)).
2. It is not instantaneous: after opening the document, the script may take several seconds to run, so that the user may see some data they shouldn't.
3. It is triggered when the document is opened. If one user is already in the document and another opens it, the script will interfere with the first user.
4. It is not secure: nothing really prevents users from accessing the data in question.

All in all, it is possible but not recommended or robust.  Having two separate sheets is still a preferred solution.

### Sample Code

This is a very basic example:

```js
function onOpen() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  const userEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  // Adjust these ranges and emails as per your requirement
  const firstUserEmail = "email1@test.test"; 
  const secondUserEmail = "email2@test.test"; 

  // Columns to hide
  const firstUserStartColumn = 1; // For example, column A
  const firstUserNumColumns = 7;  // Adjust the number of columns to hide for the first user
  const secondUserStartColumn = 9; // For example, column I
  const secondUserNumColumns = 7;  // Adjust the number of columns to hide for the second user

  // Optional: Initially show all columns
  sheet.showColumns(1, sheet.getMaxColumns());

  // Hide columns based on user email
  if (userEmail === firstUserEmail) {
    sheet.showColumns(firstUserStartColumn, firstUserNumColumns);
    sheet.hideColumns(secondUserStartColumn, secondUserNumColumns);
  } else if (userEmail === secondUserEmail) {
    sheet.showColumns(secondUserStartColumn, secondUserNumColumns);
    sheet.hideColumns(firstUserStartColumn, firstUserNumColumns);
  }
}
```