# app script on google sheet for auatomation

Tags: google-sheets, scripting, permissions

Currently i have google sheet project in which able to update scrip for user access and permissions , currently all users with link can view sheet (file all contents), specific column of work sheet can be edited by specific user to whom permission granted, other columns for same user are only view
But i want to update permission like other columns for specific user should not be visible till some time (time based view)

i am trying to permit specific cells in sheet username wise but dont have option to hide contents of specific cells to specific users

Answer (score 0):

You cannot display different data to different users in Google Sheets. You could use scripts to hide certain rows/columns when specific users open the spreadsheet, however, there are many limitations and it is not the route I can recommend going. You can check out code and details in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77806438/23220956).

The standard way of limiting visibility in Google Sheets is to use different spreadsheets for different users and combine data in one main spreadsheet accessible only to some people.